# C++ vector class to store pointers to objects

Tags: c++, vector

I have a Polygon class. Currently, the coordinates of the polygon are stored in a double array, where the number of rows is specified by "n", and the number of columns is just 3 (x, y, z).

I want to rewrite this using the stl vector instead (i.e. each element in the vector would be a pointer to a float array of size three). How would this be done? Like is this a valid declaration?

```
vector<float*> vertices;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
struct Vector3 {

 Vector3( float x, float y, float z):_x(x),_y(y),_z(z) )
 {
 }

 float _x , _y , _z;
};

std::vector<Vector3> vertices;
```

No need for a pointer, since it will add the complexity of managing the memory (if it was allocated by new), because std::vector won't own the pointer, and you will have to delete it.

Also std::vector is guaranteed to be contiguous in memory so it's safe to take the address of the first element,

```
&vertices[0]
```

And you can pass it to an API like openGL for example.

Adding new elements is also easy, you either create a constructor or set the elements one by one.

Example for a constructor:

```
vertices.push_back(Vector3( x, y, z ));
```

It's also a better practice to allocate your memory once at the beginning.

```
vertices.reserve( verticeCount);
```

Comment: How to add elements may not be immediately obvious: vertices.push_back(Vector3());

Comment: Using pointers does not lead to managing memory. The pointers could point to objects whose lifetime is already managed or is automatic. Still, using values is the way to go unless you really need reference semantics.

Comment: @TonyWilk Alternatives? I will be glad to add it to the answer.

Comment: So I did something like this: std::vector<gVector3> vertices;

But I get an error, "vector in namespace std does not include type." Do I need to include a particular header?

Comment: @AmazingVal you need to use std::vector, you also need to include<vector>

Comment: sorry, one more question! in this case, should i initialize the vector to null in my default constructor for the Polygon class?

Answer (score 0):

With C++11 you could do this:

```
std::vector<std::tuple<float, float, float>> points;
```

if you don't have C++11, you could use boost to get tuple:

```
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>

std::vector<boost::tuple<float, float, float> > points;
```

or you could have a struct to hold your three floats:

```
struct Points
{
  float x_;
  float y_;
  float z_;
};

std::vector<Points> points;
```

Stay away from raw pointers when you don't need them. It's much safer to rely on STL containers or to define your own structs/classes to hold things.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can also create a struct `Point`, which stores a 3D point and make a vector which uses the struct:

```
struct Point {
  double x, y, z;
}

vector<Point> points;
```

Use the vector as you would use it normally. You can also store pointers to points in the vector if you prefer that.

Answer (score 0):

`vector < vector <float> (3)> (n) ;` this will do the job